# jQuery plugin doesn't work (sometimes... and suddenly)

Tags: jquery

In these days I'm studying jQuery and JavaScript, so I decided to add the Google Hosted Library for jQuery in my code, to be specific, on head tag. It looks like that:

```
<head>
<!-- Other things like meta tags and css reference are above this-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js" async></script>
    <script> src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js" async></script>
</head>
```

I wanted to hide my header tag and show it with a jQuery effect after a div be clicked. Just for "initial test" I did the following command on jQuery:

```
//js/javascript.js file
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('header').hide():
});
```

But not even this simple thing works. I already changed the place of script tag (putting it  before of the end of tag body) and the Hosted Library. Not changed...

My header:

```
<header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <a href="#">
     <li>
      Home
     </li>
   </a>
    <a href="#">
     <li>
      Archives
     </li>
   </a>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

If you guys help me, I really will appreciate.
<strike>Sorry for any English error, I'm not a native speaker</strike>

Edit:
I forgot to write: the plugin worked sometimes but stopped for no reason.

Problem solved.
As Robert Rozas said, I had to remove every async on script tags.
Thank you guys for helping.

Comment: Remove the `async` on every script ;)

Answer (score 0):

Load your jquery library before the local JavaScript file.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js" async></script>
<script src="js/javascript.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

---

Also, you're missing the semi-colon. The statement should be:

```
$('header').hide();
//                ^ Notice the semi-colon here
```

Comment: It "worked". I changed the server but it does not work when I put the $(document).ready(function() {}); statement. Just when I started in $(function() {/**/});

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that was missing. But still no work.

Comment: @jefersonhuan you need to learn to use browser developer tools console to look for obvious errors that get thrown there

Comment: @charlietfi, thank you for your sincerity. But to learn those developer tools I should know (at least the basic of) the language, right? Otherwise how could I understand the possible errors? As I said, I just did it as a test. And actually the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the right answer was to remove the async attribute on every script, like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```